# Are $\Delta G = RT \ln{\frac{Q}{K}}$ and $\Delta S = -\frac{RT\ln{\frac{Q}{K}}-q_p}{T}$ legitimate relations?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry

While messing around with $\Delta G = \Delta G^\ominus + RT\ln{Q}$ and $\Delta G^\ominus = -RT\ln{K}$, I found this relation:

$$\Delta G = RT \ln{\frac{Q}{K}}$$

which helped me clarify how $\Delta G$ is affected by changes in $Q$, but I wanted to make sure that it is actually true before I rely on it for such things.

Also, would this mean that:

$$\Delta S = -\frac{RT\ln{\frac{Q}{K}}-\Delta H}{T}$$

and therefore, at constant pressure:

$$\Delta S = -\frac{RT\ln{\frac{Q}{K}}-q_p}{T}$$

holds true? That is, that change in entropy can be increased by essentially adding product, or is that cancelled out by the heat exchange?

Comment: Let's consider the special case of an ideal gas.  If your development is valid in general, then it must work for that special case.  In your equation $\Delta G = RT \ln{\frac{Q}{K}}$, what are the initial and final thermodynamic equilibrium states, according to your understanding?

Comment: Sorry it took so long for me to respond. I clicked the box for SE to email me when responses are posted, and I never got such an email.

Comment: Anyway, according to my understanding, $\Delta S = nR \ln{\frac{V_f}{V_i}}$. Messing around with this for a bit, I get $e^\frac{q_p - pV}{RT} = \frac{QV_f}{KV_i}$ and, if I'm being honest, this doesn't make sense to me because $pV = w$ and I don't expect a gas at constant pressure to be doing any work. Intuitively, though, I can make sense of it _if_ $Q$ is greater than $K$ because more gas was added to the system, so I would expect the equilibrium reached after that addition to feature all gasses present in larger amounts. I would expect the entropy to therefore increase. Does that work?

Comment: You still haven't answered my question about the initial and final states of the system described by the equation I asked about.  If you can't precisely identify the initial and final states that apply, how can you possibly discuss the change in a function of state?  Here's a hint:  The initial state is pure reactants in stoichiometric proportions in separate containers at specified pressures (not necessarily each being one bar).

Comment: Maybe you should assume I don't get what you're trying to say and be more explicit. If we're talking about taking a system in equilibrium that we alter by adding more product, then the initial state is a gas mixture with more product than at equilibrium and the final state is equilibrium. Whether we end up with higher pressure or lower pressure depends on the reaction.

Comment: For the final state, we have pure products in stoichiometric proportions in separate containers at specified pressures (not necessarily each being one bar).  That's what the equation $\Delta G=RT\ln{\frac{Q}{K}}$ is implying.  If the initial state values and the final state values of the pressures in the containers happen to equal the partial pressures in an equilibrium mixture of the gases, then Q = K and $\Delta G=0$.  Note however, whatever process is devised to go from the initial state to the final state in this case does not involve constant pressure.  So, q is not equal to $\Delta H$